# Jasmine/Karma not finding Angular modules

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying unit testing with Jasmine and Karma, but for some reason my Angular modules cannot be found. I've modified code from examples:

karma.config.js:

```
files: [
  'lib/angular.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'js/app.js',
  'js/controllers.js',
  'js/factories.js',
  'tests/**/*.js'
]
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
      templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
      controller: 'TestCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

controllers.js:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    console.log('Test Controller');
    $scope.isActive = function(route) {
        return route === $location.path();
    };
});
```

test-spec.js:

```
describe('TestCtrl testing', function () {
    var scope, $location, createController;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$location_) {
        $location = _$location_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        createController = function () {
            return $controller('TestCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        };
    })); 

    it('should...', function () {
        var controller = createController();
        $location.path('/test');
        expect($location.path()).toBe('/test');
        expect(scope.isActive('/test')).toBe(true);
        expect(scope.isActive('/contact')).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

error message:
**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**

I also tried with: **beforeEach(module('TestCtrl'))**, but it did not help.

What have I missed?

Comment: It should be `beforeEach(module('app'))`. Also looks like you forgot to add ngAnimate to karma files config: `files: ['lib/angular.js', 'lib/angular-route.js', 'lib/angular-mocks.js', ...]`.

Comment: That took care of it! I wonder why the module('app') wasn't mentioned in the example... Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems I can see. In describe section there must be main module injection:

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

The second problem is that you forgot to add ngAnimate module to Karma files config array:

```
files: [
    'lib/angular.js', 
    'lib/angular-route.js', // <-- this guy
    'lib/angular-mocks.js', 
    ...
]
```

Comment: You seem to have this sussed – can you help with a similar question here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234610/how-to-inject-ngroute-into-jasmine-karma-angularjs-unit-test