# How to inject ngRoute into Jasmine / Karma AngularJS unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, ngroute

I'm trying to get a basic unit test example working. It all works fine with this app.js

```
var whapp = angular.module('whapp', [])
.filter('reverse',[function(){
    return function(string){
        return string.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
}]);
```

and this spec.js

```
describe('Filters', function(){ //describe your object type
    beforeEach(module('whapp')); //load module
    describe('reverse',function(){ //describe your app name
        var reverse, rootScope;
        beforeEach(inject(function($filter){ //initialize your filter
            reverse = $filter('reverse',{});
        }));
        it('Should reverse a string', function(){  //write tests
            expect(reverse('rahil')).toBe('lihar'); //pass
        });
    });
});
```

with this karma files config

```
files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'app/js/*.js',
      'tests/*.js'
]
```

The problem occurs when I try to inject ngRoute into my module in app.js like so

```
var whapp = angular.module('whapp', ['ngRoute'])
.filter('reverse',[function(){
    return function(string){
        return string.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
}]);
```

In which case I get the following error in karma [UPDATE: this error occurs even if I don't load the angular-mock.js library into karma as shown above]

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'reverse('rahil')') in tests/spec.js (line 9)
```

So... how do I inject ngRoute into spec.js correctly? I've tried a variety of things, none of which worked.

Comment: What happens if you don't load the mock of ng-route, but just allow the one in angular.js to load?

Comment: @Amy Blankenship. I get the error described. I'm not loading the mock of ng-route because I don't know how to... that's precisely the question – how can I load the mock of ng-route? Unless you're talking about the files attribute in the karma config? If I remove those I still get the same error.

Comment: Um, you absolutely are unless it's just a phantom file that doesn't exist at the path `'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-route/angular-route.js'`. If it does not exist there, then that could well cause the problem.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was just not being clear. I'm loading it as a library yes. However, if I don't load it as a library I still get the same error. What I meant by "I'm not loading the mock" is that I'm not injecting it as a dependency within spec.js because I don't know how to – I think I need to but it's not clear how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you get this error because `PhantomJS` fails to instantiate your main Angular module `whapp`. One possible reason is, that the file `node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-route/angular-route.js` is missing.

Obviously, you are using `npm` to manage your dependencies. So try to replace your current file with:

```
node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js
```

The same for the `ui-route` module:

```
node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I was being a really dumb n00b... basically the inclusion paths in karma config were wrong, as some commenters tried to point out albeit in less clear language. Well done!

Comment: You are welcome. Just a tip, next time try to switch to chrome it will throw a meaningful error !